# Subscript out of Bounds in tidymodels tuning

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

When using the tidymodels dataset, I run into a "subscript out of bounds error". I am using the Ames house prices dataset from Kaggle by the way.

First, I create my recipe:

```
data.split = initial_split(house.prices, prop=0.8)

train.data = training(data.split)
test.data = testing(data.split)

# Create recipe - OLS
sales.rec = recipe(SalePrice ~., data = train.data) %>%
  step_log(SalePrice, LotArea, GrLivArea, TotRmsAbvGrd) %>%
  update_role(Id, SalePrice, new_role = "ID") %>%
  step_num2factor(MSSubClass, levels = as.character(unique(house.prices$SalePrice))) %>%
  step_unknown(PoolQC, Fence, MiscFeature, BsmtQual, BsmtCond, BsmtExposure, BsmtFinType1,
               FireplaceQu, GarageType, GarageQual, GarageCond, new_level = "None") %>%
  step_mutate(PorchArea = OpenPorchSF+EnclosedPorch+`3SsnPorch`+ScreenPorch) %>%
  step_mutate(garage.age = YrSold - GarageYrBlt,
         house.age = YrSold - YearBuilt,
         renovation.age = YrSold - YearRemodAdd
         ) %>%
  step_mutate(has.garage = (GarageType != NA),
         has.basement = (BsmtExposure != NA),
         has.pool = (PoolQC != NA),
         is.new = house.age==0
         ) %>%
  step_cut(OverallQual, breaks = c(2.5, 6.5, 8.5)) %>%
  step_cut(OverallCond, breaks = c(2.5, 6.5, 8.5)) %>%
  step_mutate(house.age = log(1+house.age)) %>%
  step_rm(-c(SalePrice, house.age, renovation.age, 
             has.garage, has.basement, has.pool, is.new,
             MSZoning, LotArea, Alley, LotShape, Utilities, Neighborhood, OverallQual, OverallCond, 
             ExterCond, Foundation,
             BsmtFinSF1, Heating, HeatingQC, CentralAir, GrLivArea, FullBath, KitchenQual, TotRmsAbvGrd,
             PavedDrive, PorchArea, MiscVal,SaleCondition)) %>% 
  step_other(all_nominal_predictors(), all_factor(), all_string()) %>%
  step_string2factor(all_string_predictors()) %>%
  step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_median(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_unknown(all_factor_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())
```

Then I set up a ranger random forest model:

```
my.rf = rand_forest(mtry = tune(), trees = 2000, min_n=tune()) %>%
  set_engine("ranger") %>%
  set_mode("regression")
```

Finally, I create a workflow and try to tune the model:

```
tree.grid = expand.grid(min_n=c(2,14,27,40), mtry = c(4, 8, 12))
folds = rsample::vfold_cv(train.data, v = 5)
metric = metric_set(rmse)


set_dependency("rand_forest", "ranger", "ranger", mode = "regression")
# Random forest
my.rf.rec = sales.rec %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_other(all_nominal_predictors())
my.rf.wflow = workflow() %>%
  add_model(my.rf) %>%
  add_recipe(my.rf.rec)

my.rf.res = my.rf.wflow %>%
  tune_grid(
  resamples = folds,
  metrics = metric,
  grid = tree.grid
)
```

However, upon running that final lines, I get the following error:
"x Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/12: Error in y.mat[, 2]: subscript out of bounds" (for lots of preprocessor and models), followed by "Warning: All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more information." (if I run the command indicated in the error, it just gives me "Error in y.mat[, 2]: subscript out of bounds")

I've tried googling everything, but cannot find the source of the error, any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: Here's the head of the dataset, hopefully it helps?

```
structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), MSSubClass = c(60, 20, 
60, 70, 60, 50), MSZoning = c("RL", "RL", "RL", "RL", "RL", "RL"
), LotFrontage = c(65, 80, 68, 60, 84, 85), LotArea = c(8450, 
9600, 11250, 9550, 14260, 14115), Street = c("Pave", "Pave", 
"Pave", "Pave", "Pave", "Pave"), Alley = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    LotShape = c("Reg", "Reg", "IR1", "IR1", "IR1", "IR1"), LandContour = c("Lvl", 
    "Lvl", "Lvl", "Lvl", "Lvl", "Lvl"), Utilities = c("AllPub", 
    "AllPub", "AllPub", "AllPub", "AllPub", "AllPub"), LotConfig = c("Inside", 
    "FR2", "Inside", "Corner", "FR2", "Inside"), LandSlope = c("Gtl", 
    "Gtl", "Gtl", "Gtl", "Gtl", "Gtl"), Neighborhood = c("CollgCr", 
    "Veenker", "CollgCr", "Crawfor", "NoRidge", "Mitchel"), Condition1 = c("Norm", 
    "Feedr", "Norm", "Norm", "Norm", "Norm"), Condition2 = c("Norm", 
    "Norm", "Norm", "Norm", "Norm", "Norm"), BldgType = c("1Fam", 
    "1Fam", "1Fam", "1Fam", "1Fam", "1Fam"), HouseStyle = c("2Story", 
    "1Story", "2Story", "2Story", "2Story", "1.5Fin"), OverallQual = c(7, 
    6, 7, 7, 8, 5), OverallCond = c(5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5), YearBuilt = c(2003, 
    1976, 2001, 1915, 2000, 1993), YearRemodAdd = c(2003, 1976, 
    2002, 1970, 2000, 1995), RoofStyle = c("Gable", "Gable", 
    "Gable", "Gable", "Gable", "Gable"), RoofMatl = c("CompShg", 
    "CompShg", "CompShg", "CompShg", "CompShg", "CompShg"), Exterior1st = c("VinylSd", 
    "MetalSd", "VinylSd", "Wd Sdng", "VinylSd", "VinylSd"), Exterior2nd = c("VinylSd", 
    "MetalSd", "VinylSd", "Wd Shng", "VinylSd", "VinylSd"), MasVnrType = c("BrkFace", 
    "None", "BrkFace", "None", "BrkFace", "None"), MasVnrArea = c(196, 
    0, 162, 0, 350, 0), ExterQual = c("Gd", "TA", "Gd", "TA", 
    "Gd", "TA"), ExterCond = c("TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", 
    "TA"), Foundation = c("PConc", "CBlock", "PConc", "BrkTil", 
    "PConc", "Wood"), BsmtQual = c("Gd", "Gd", "Gd", "TA", "Gd", 
    "Gd"), BsmtCond = c("TA", "TA", "TA", "Gd", "TA", "TA"), 
    BsmtExposure = c("No", "Gd", "Mn", "No", "Av", "No"), BsmtFinType1 = c("GLQ", 
    "ALQ", "GLQ", "ALQ", "GLQ", "GLQ"), BsmtFinSF1 = c(706, 978, 
    486, 216, 655, 732), BsmtFinType2 = c("Unf", "Unf", "Unf", 
    "Unf", "Unf", "Unf"), BsmtFinSF2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BsmtUnfSF = c(150, 
    284, 434, 540, 490, 64), TotalBsmtSF = c(856, 1262, 920, 
    756, 1145, 796), Heating = c("GasA", "GasA", "GasA", "GasA", 
    "GasA", "GasA"), HeatingQC = c("Ex", "Ex", "Ex", "Gd", "Ex", 
    "Ex"), CentralAir = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), Electrical = c("SBrkr", 
    "SBrkr", "SBrkr", "SBrkr", "SBrkr", "SBrkr"), `1stFlrSF` = c(856, 
    1262, 920, 961, 1145, 796), `2ndFlrSF` = c(854, 0, 866, 756, 
    1053, 566), LowQualFinSF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GrLivArea = c(1710, 
    1262, 1786, 1717, 2198, 1362), BsmtFullBath = c(1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), BsmtHalfBath = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), FullBath = c(2, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 1), HalfBath = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), BedroomAbvGr = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 1), KitchenAbvGr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KitchenQual = c("Gd", 
    "TA", "Gd", "Gd", "Gd", "TA"), TotRmsAbvGrd = c(8, 6, 6, 
    7, 9, 5), Functional = c("Typ", "Typ", "Typ", "Typ", "Typ", 
    "Typ"), Fireplaces = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), FireplaceQu = c(NA, 
    "TA", "TA", "Gd", "TA", NA), GarageType = c("Attchd", "Attchd", 
    "Attchd", "Detchd", "Attchd", "Attchd"), GarageYrBlt = c(2003, 
    1976, 2001, 1998, 2000, 1993), GarageFinish = c("RFn", "RFn", 
"RFn", "Unf", "RFn", "Unf"), GarageCars = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    2), GarageArea = c(548, 460, 608, 642, 836, 480), GarageQual = c("TA", 
    "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA"), GarageCond = c("TA", "TA", 
    "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA"), PavedDrive = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y"), WoodDeckSF = c(0, 298, 0, 0, 192, 40), OpenPorchSF = c(61, 
    0, 42, 35, 84, 30), EnclosedPorch = c(0, 0, 0, 272, 0, 0), 
    `3SsnPorch` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 320), ScreenPorch = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), PoolArea = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PoolQC = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Fence = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "MnPrv"), MiscFeature = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Shed"), MiscVal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700), 
    MoSold = c(2, 5, 9, 2, 12, 10), YrSold = c(2008, 2007, 2008, 
    2006, 2008, 2009), SaleType = c("WD", "WD", "WD", "WD", "WD", 
    "WD"), SaleCondition = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Abnorml", 
    "Normal", "Normal"), SalePrice = c(208500, 181500, 223500, 
    140000, 250000, 143000)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the exact data set you are using. The naming of the variables and the encoding doesn't match what I can find online. From your code it appears that `MSSubClass` is numeric, and the dataset includes a `Id` variable

Comment: "subscript out of bounds" typically means something is being indexed beyond what exists. I'd first check anywhere where you are manually indexing something (i.e., with actual numbers instead of variables as in your `tree.grid` or `folds` variables). But as @EmilHvitfeldt said, we can't really help you without some data to troubleshoot. Can you post data (or a subset) here with `dput()`?

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes : I added the head of the dataset, hope this helps. I cannot find any issue with where I manually indexed anything (though I might just not be familiar with how the issue would present itself)

Comment: @EmilHvitfeldt I added the head of the dataset :) It's from Kaggle originally

Comment: As it seems, I did a very elementary mistake - I removed SalePrice from its role as predictor by assigning it to role ID in the recipe. That was a leftover from when I had seperate log price variable as predictor. Silly me